# How to update a Ext JS 4 grid when popup form is submitted

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Please point me to an Ext JS 4 code sample of a grid with records editable via a popup form. It seems to be a common use case, but I can only find editable grids with editing in place.

My approach:

1. Each row in the grid has an Edit button, which shows `Ext.window.Window` with an item `Ext.form.Panel`.
2. When the  form is submitted I have all the fields, which correspond to a record in the grid store.
3. I get record using:

   `var storeRecord = grid.getStore().getAt(index);`

   But when I modify properties of this record, and hide the form window, the grid does not show updated values.

Am I missing some step? Do I need to force refresh? Or maybe there is a standard way to configure the grid with an editor as a form panel?

Answer (score 1):

After two days of searches, trials and errors, I found the solution:

```
grid.getView().refresh();
```

I wish there was a faster way for Ext learning curve. :(

Comment: How did you modify the record? I was under the impression that if you do "storeRecord.set('yourProperty', 'yourValue')" the store should automatically pick it up

Comment: Thanks for formatting Ben Scott, I looked at this questions shortly after it was posted and thought it was asking something completely different that I did not know the answer to. @Chao "storeRecord.set('yourProperty', 'yourValue')" _will_ update the store data but you still have to use "grid.getView().refresh()" as the OP discovered to make your grid match the data in the store.

Comment: @Geronimo I meant in my original comment that the grid should automatically pick up the change. Because modifying a record by using "set" will trigger a datachanged event in the store, which the grid's view is listening to. That's how the grid displays that little red triangle on the top left of the cell that contains a dirty record